# Why is componentShown() not called?

Tags: java, swing, events, listener

I have a `CardDetailsPanel` class which contains several `JLabel`s and `JTextField`s. This class in contained in a `AddCardsPanel` and is initialized as follows:

```
    cardDetailsPanel = new CardDetailsPanel(true);
    add(cardDetailsPanel, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

I also have a `JLabel` that contains instructions. I want to update this label when the `CardDetailsPanel` first appears and when focus changes to each `JTextField`. I have found the `addFocusListener()` method that will work for the later. However, my `compenentShown()` method isn't working for the former:

```
    addComponentListener(new java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter() {
        public void componentShown(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent evt) {
            formComponentShown(evt);
        }
    });
```

(Okay, I know this is ugly. It was generated by NetBeans.)

```
private void formComponentShown(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent evt) {
    this.frame = (BaseballFrame) this.getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent();
}
```

(Yah, this is even uglier. I'll deal with the chained `getParent()` calls later. I want to do other things here as well.)

So why doesn't my listener get called? And how do I write a listener that will perform some actions whenever my `CardDetailsPanel` appears on the screen?

Comment: I think you'll find that `componentShown` relates more to `setVisible`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use an [`AncestorListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/AncestorListener.html) as described in [dialog focus](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/03/14/dialog-focus/).

> When a `JDialog` (or `JFrame` for that matter) is made visible, focus is placed on the first focusable component by default. There may be times when you want to change this behaviour. The obvious solution would be to invoke the `requestFocusInWindow()` method on the component you wish to receive focus. The problem is that this doesn’t work all the time.
>
> ...
>
> The problem is .. a component can’t request focus unless it has been added to a “realized” dialog. A realized dialog basically means that the Swing `JDialog` has been added to a peer component that represents a dialog on the underlying OS. This occurs when you invoke the `pack()` or `setVisible(true)` methods on the `JDialog`.

And that is where the ancestor listener comes in handy.  For a component in a modal dialog, it will be fired once the component becomes visible, and ***is*** realized & focusable.

**Edit:**
The above comment applies to components in any Swing container, including JFrame and `JPanel`.